# Add conditional to a null coalescing operation

Tags: c#

I have an existing method return using a null-coalescing operation:

```
return GetOverrideColor(overrideFlags, colorUsage) ??
       GetColor(colorExpression, field, purpose, defaultColor);
```

Is there a way to add an additional condition to this shorthand that would only run the GetOverrideColor method if x = true?

This is what I have in longhand:

```
CustomColor color = null;

if (overrideRequired)
    color = GetOverrideColor(overrideFlags, colorUsage);

if (color == null)
    color = GetColor(colorExpression, field, purpose, defaultColor);

return color;
```

Comment: This would be less complicated if `GetOverrideColor()` wouldn't be able to return a nullable `Color`. You sure that's needed?

Comment: The longer version is easier to understand. So why look for a shorter version? That won't improve anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
return (overrideRequired ? GetOverrideColor(overrideFlags, colorUsage) : null) ??
       GetColor(colorExpression, field, purpose, defaultColor);
```

If `overrideRequired` is `false`, `null` is used for the left-hand operand to `??`. If it's `true`, `GetOverrideColor(overrideFlags, colorUsage)` is called and used as the left-hand operand to `??`.

Alternatively, you might update `GetOverrideColor` to accept a flag for this (perhaps one of `overrideFlags`?), though calling a function passing in a value that tells it to just immediately return `null` may be a bit off...

Comment: Having said that, it might be getting a bit complicated to read for people coming to the code later vs. spelling it out as you did at the end of your question.

Comment: Thanks, I think your response is perfect, and it seems so simple now, I don't know why I didn't think of it.  However you make a good argument about the shorthand vs longhand - I'm finding this a lot lately in other areas with readability vs optimised code

Comment: @MarkClayton - My pleasure. FWIW, I doubt the (perhaps) more readable version is less optimized in any real way anyway. :-)